# How can I Convert .doc, .docx, .html to PDF inside database using PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pdf, converters

I have Oracle 11.2.0.1 standard edition running on Windows 2008 R2 servers

I want to be able to convert word documents (.doc, .docx, .rtf) and html files to PDF inside the database using PL/SQL

I've had a look at http://www.muhimbi.com/ but there are no Oracle specific examples and whilst I know you can load java into the database it's not something I've done before.

I've also looked at BCL easyPDF server which I could export the doc, convert it in the windows environment and then pull the doc back into the database but if possible I'd like a cleaner solution

Does anyone have suggestions for any good tools to do this (obviously I realise I need to pay for the tool). It needs to be scalable as potentially there could be hundreds of documents converted at a time

We already have PLPDF and the long term solution is to write routines to use this to create the PDF's in the first place but it is going to be a long time before we get around to doing this everywhere that we need to in our application and we need something in place now.

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Try using the solution in this post http://geekswithblogs.net/robertphyatt/archive/2011/11/19/converting-.docx-to-pdf-or-.doc-to-pdf-or-.doc.aspx

Comment: Thanks but that is still outside the database, I was looking for any solutions using PL/SQL